# Fabric sudo() not respecting env.password

Tags: python, sudo, fabric

I'm trying to prefill `env.password` using `--initial-password-prompt`, but remote is throwing back some strangeness. Let's say that I'm trying to `cat` a root-owned file as testuser, with 600 permissions on the file. I'm calling `sudo('cat /home/testuser/test.txt')`, and getting this back:

```
[testuser@testserver] sudo: cat /home/testuser/test.txt
[testuser@testserver] out: cat: /home/testuser/test.txt: Permission denied
[testuser@testserver] out:
Fatal error: sudo() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!
Requested: cat /home/testuser/test.txt
Executed: sudo -S -p 'sudo password:'  -u "testuser"  /bin/bash -l -c "cat /home/testuser/test.txt"
```

Is that piping the prompt right back into the input? I tried using `sudo()` with `pty=False` to see if it was an issue with the pseudoterminal, but to no avail.

Here's the weird part: calling `run('sudo cat /home/testuser/test.txt')` and invoking `fab` without `--initial-password-prompt` passes back a password prompt from remote, and on entering the password, everything works fine.

Naturally, running `ssh -t testuser@testserver 'sudo cat /home/user/test.txt'` prompts for a password and returns the contents of the file correctly. Do I have an issue with my server's shell config, or is the issue with how I'm using `sudo()`?

Down the line, I'm likely to set up a deploy user with no-password `sudo` and restricted commands. That'll probably moot the issue, but I'd like to figure this one out if possible. I'm running an Ubuntu 14.10 VPS, in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, my mistake. I had foolishly set `env.sudo_user` to my deploy user testuser, thinking that it was specifying the invoking user on remote. In fact, it was specifying the target user, and I was attempting to `sudo` into myself. Whoops.